# Virtuemart 2 - New 'Add to cart' button with Ajax on VM default front Page

Tags: jquery, e-commerce, joomla2.5, virtuemart

I am trying to add an "add to cart button" in VM, on the default virtuemart frontpage like this:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo JRoute::_ ('index.php'); ?>">
    <input name="quantity" type="hidden" value="1" />
    <div class="addtocart-bar">
        <span class="addtocart-button">
            <?php echo shopFunctionsF::getAddToCartButton ($product->orderable); ?>
        </span>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" class="pname" value="<?php echo htmlentities($product->product_name, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8') ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_virtuemart"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="view" value="cart"/>
    <noscript><input type="hidden" name="task" value="add"/></noscript>
    <input type="hidden" name="virtuemart_product_id[]" value="<?php echo $product->virtuemart_product_id ?>"/>
    <input name="quantity[]" type="hidden" value="1" />
</form>
```

The problem is that this does not seem to add the order to the VM session cart, and subsequently, the S5 Column Ajax Cart is also not updating.  It simply takes me to the cart page without adding anything to the cart.

I am using the ajax popup functionality in VM, so basically it should pop up the notification, which after I close the modal, should leave me on the same page without redirecting me to the cart.  I have an idea that I am missing some JS or PHP method, but I can't figure it out.

I am doing this in default_products.php in a html override in the template folder.

Note, this functionality does work on all other pages that had an add-to-cart button on them out of the box.

Am I missing something that I need to have on the page?

I am running latest VM2 and Joomla 2.5.14 Stable.  I am using the Virtuemarttemplates.net "Echo"  template.

Thanks

Jacques

Answer (score 0):

Good Question, i have implemented this concept in one of my custom component page. you can use it anywhere only you have to provide product id and quantity.
following is the code you have to implement to your page:

**Dont forget to change the variable in following div:**

**quantity= "1"** replace 1 with your quantity

**"$res->virtuemart_product_id"** replace it with your product id

**Place the following div inside your page:**

```
<div class="addtocart-bar">
  <span class="addtocart-button" style="float:right !important;"> 
    <input type="submit" url='<?php echo JRoute::_("index.php?option=com_virtuemart&nosef=1&view=cart&task=addJS&format=json&lang=en&quantity=1&quantity%5B%5D=1&view=cart&virtuemart_product_id%5B%5D=$res->virtuemart_product_id&option=com_virtuemart"); ?>' title="Add to Cart" value="Add to Cart" id="btn_addtocart" class="bttn right" name="addtocart">
  </span>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

**and at the top of page you have to add following code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery("[name=addtocart]").click(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        var url = $(this).attr('url');

            jQuery.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: url,
                async:false,
                data:{'p_id' : 1 },
                success: function(html){
                    var msg ="<div id='fancybox-content'><div style='width:auto;height:auto;overflow: auto;position:relative;'><div class='popUp_Box'><p>This item has been added to your shopping cart.</p><a class='continue bttn rmv_brdr btn_fix' href='index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=categories&virtuemart_category_id=0'>Keep Shopping</a><?php if($user->id){ ?><a href='index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=cart' class='showcart floatright bttn btn_fix'>Check Out</a><?php }else{ ?><a href='index.php?option=com_users&view=login&checkout=1' class='showcart floatright bttn btn_fix'>Check Out</a><?php } ?></div></div></div><a id='fancybox-close' style='display: block;'></a>";

                    jQuery.fancybox({
                                "titlePosition" :   "inside",
                                "transitionIn"  :   "elastic",
                                "transitionOut" :   "elastic",
                                "type"          :   "html",
                                "autoCenter"    :   true,
                                "closeBtn"      :   true,
                                "closeClick"    :   false,
                                "content"       :   msg
                            }
                        );

                }
            });
    });

    });
</script>
```

The Above Script will work if you have fancybox plugin saved at your root folder, for that please download fancybox plugin from "http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#license". I have used fancybox because when the order is added to cart your order confirmation will appear in fancybox, that looks great. i am also attaching one of the image to show where you have to add fancybox plugin folder. I hope this will help you a lot.

[image: Place fancybox plugin folder at this position.]

Regards

Mohit :)